# Why do I get the 405 error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, node.js

I'm very new to web programming, and I'm trying to set up a little website with a serverside.
Here's the code:

```js
class userData {
  catchDropDownSelection() {
    this.dropDownSelection = $('#xDropDown').prop('selectedIndex');
  }
}

class sendData {
  constructor(userData) {
    this.userDataClone = userData;
  }

  sendDropDownSelection() {
    //this.userDataClone.catchDropDownSelection();
    $.post("MyFirstPhP.php", {
      userSelection: "dummy" //this.userDataClone.dropDownSelection
    }, function(data) {
      //this.testFunction()
      $('#testOutput').html("data");
      //document.getElementById("testOutput").innerHTML = "data"
    }).fail(function() {
      console.log("$.post failed!");
    })
  }

  testFunction() {
    //document.getElementById("testOutput").innerHTML = "data"
    $('#testOutput').html("data");
  }
}

var userDataInstance = new userData;
var sendDataInstance = new sendData(userDataInstance);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>PHP is Awesome!</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyFirstPhP.css">
</head>

<body>
  <select id="xDropDown">
    <option value="test1">test1</option>
    <option value="test2">test2</option>
  </select>
  <button onclick="sendDataInstance.sendDropDownSelection()">ClickMe!</button>
  <p id="testOutput">not yet</p>
  <script src="MyFirstPhP.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The php code is here:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $dropDownSelection = $_POST['userSelection'];
  echo $dropDownSelection
  //$dropDownSelection = $dropDownSelection . "wurde verarbeitet!";
?>
```

I'm running my server with node.js on localhost, port 8080. So far it works, when I've started the server I can load my page and interact with it. 
However, when I'm pressing the button, which triggers the AJAX call to the php, I'm getting the following error in my console log:

> jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8080/MyFirstPhP.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)

I must add that I'm running the whole thing without admin privileges. However, since the webserver somehow seems to run as I can load the website, I wonder if it could be due to another reason than low privileges on the machine.

Comment: _"I'm running my server with node.js on localhost, port 8080"_ that's not going to run your PHP scripts

Comment: erm, ok? And what do I need instead or in addition?

Comment: Something that runs PHP like php-fpm (which you [can execute via node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-phpfpm)) or mod_php (in Apache).

Comment: You need PHP in general. Could start its own little PHP webserver by running `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: yeah Ive tried a portable XAMPP, but I didnt get apache to run yet :/ node.js for some reason did start a server, so I decided to give it a try.

Comment: @kerbholz 3
Okay, php runs a server, Im getting this output in my cmd when running your command:
PHP 7.2.8RC1 Development Server started at Wed Jul 25 09:44:24 2018
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000

However, when I'm trying to load http://127.0.0.1:8000 via my Browser, I'm getting the following site: https://imgur.com/8YJjqNX

Since the php command seems to run, i wonder why loading the site doesnt work, especially since when I hosted with node.js, the site did at least load.

Comment: PHP is looking for `index.php` to serve from root. I saw a `MyFirstPHP.php` in your screenie, see if `127.0.0.1:8000/MyFirstPHP.php` works. Or rename that file to `index.php`. Here's [more info](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) on the server.

Comment: YEAH THANKS MAN! :D 
This worked for me! :)))